# How to use same module on multiple dashboard pages in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am building a Shiny dashboard and I want two different pages of the dashboard the same module functions I created. Now, it looks like the following:

```
shinyUI(
dashboardPage(skin = "red",
            dashboardHeader(title = "Tool",titleWidth = '275px'), 
            dashboardSidebar(width = '275px', disable = FALSE, collapsed = FALSE,
                             sidebarMenu(id = "sidebartabs",
                                         menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                                         menuItem("Analyse data", tabName = "analysedata", icon = icon("bar-chart")),
                                         menuItem("Predict", tabName = "analysedata", icon = icon("chart-line")),
             )
```

Where I want to use in the menus `Analyse data` and `Predict` the same modules, `tabName = analysedata`, which is defined as:

```
 tabItem("analysedata", analyse.body)
```

where `analyse.body` is the name of the module. However, running the code above makes the dashboard unresponsive. When I comment `menuItem("Predict", tabName = "analysedata", icon = icon("chart-line"))` the dashboard works fine, only with just the `Analyse data` page.

Does anyone know why my approach does not work?